# Why does this print if it's above value 99?

Tags: python, numbers

```
mySpeed = input("What is your speed? ")

if mySpeed < ("50"):

    print ("safe")
```

Why does this print if the value is above 99?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are comparing two strings, not two integers. A string is a sequence and for a sequence comparison works [as follows](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types):

> The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

So if you take a number large than `'99'`, e.g. `'100'` it will take the first character `'1'` and compare it to `'5'` (first character of `'50'`). `'1'` is smaller than `'5'` in [ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) (`'1'==49` and `'5'==53`). So this comparison will already terminate and the result will be that indeed `'100'` is smaller than `'50'`.

For the same reason `'9'` is not smaller than `'50'`:

```
In [1]: b'9'<b'50'
Out[1]: False
```

You should compare integers, as follows:

```
mySpeed = int(input("What is your speed? "))
if mySpeed < 50:    
    print ("safe")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
mySpeed = int(input("What is your speed? "))
if mySpeed < 50:
    # same as before
```

Explanation: you should read a number and compare it against a number. Your code currently is reading a string and comparing it against another string, that's not going to give the results you expect.

Answer (score 1):

"50" is a string, not a number ... try eliminating the " " ...

If mystring is a string, try a cast with the int-function - e.g.  int(mystring)

Answer (score 0):

`mySpeed < ("50")` is checking a string.  You need to be working with integers:

```
mySpeed = input("What is your speed? ")

if mySpeed < (50):
    print ("safe")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't evaluate a string as if it were an integer. Think of a string as the word "ten", whereas the integer is "10". You can't add the three letters t-e-n to an integer and result in a number. However, you can add "10+10", for example to result in "20". Your code should look like this:

```
mySpeed = int(input("What is your speed? "))

if mySpeed < 50:
      print ("safe")
```

**NOTE**: by using the `int()` function to turn users' input into an integer, you are not in fact verifying what they input. If the user inputs a string, such as "ten", your code will return an error because "ten" cannot be converted into an integer.

My answer isn't best practice, but it will "work".